# How to use adhoc build in an app

Tags: objective-c

Hi
    I have been given an adhoc distribution provision profile.
as com.compnayname.* now when i am using it in my app it is saying that invalid identifier in bundle identifier .my app name is XYZ 
Can some one tell me the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The add hoc provision profile is for an specific app you must set your bundle identifier in you Info.plist to be the same as the name from the mobile provision.